# jquery how to fill up an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, fill

i am in mobile app and i want to fill up an array with values from checkboxes.

my code is

```
if (row.flatdescription == flatdescription) {
    if (row.receiptno == 0){
        items.push('<input type="checkbox" name="code_'+ i +'" id="code_'+ i +'" value="' + row.amount + '" previous="' + row.pastpayments + '" barcode="' + row.barcode + '" todayp="' + row.todaypayments + '"/><label for="code_'+ i +'">' + row.period +'..........'+ row.amount+'</label></br>');
    }
    allbarcode[i] = row.barcode;
    previouspayments1 = previouspayments1 + row.pastpayments;
    previouspayments = previouspayments1.toFixed(2);
    sofeilon1 = sofeilon1 + row.amount;
    sofeilon = sofeilon1.toFixed(2);
    total1 = total1 + row.amount - row.pastpayments;
    total = total1.toFixed(2);
}
```

and my array code

```
function barcodeTotal() {
    barcode = [];
    barcodeamount = [];
    barcodeprevious = [];
    $("input:checked").each(function(i) {
        barcode[i] = $(this).attr("barcode");
        barcodeamount[i] = $(this).attr("value");
        barcodeprevious[i] = $(this).attr("previous");
    });
}
```

my goal is to fill barcode array like this

```
barcode [barcode: barcode, amount: value, previous: previous, ....
```

i will appreciate your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can transform your checked input fields into an array easily:

```
var checkedInputs = $("input:checked") // this contains the raw HTML-Elements
```

Now, depending on the desired result you may either *harvest* the values separately

```
var barcodes  = checkedInputs.map(function() { return $(this).attr('barcode')  })
var amounts   = checkedInputs.map(function() { return $(this).attr('amount')   })
var previouss = checkedInputs.map(function() { return $(this).attr('previous') })
```

or, what might be even better, as objects just like twilson suggested

```
var results = checkedInputs.map(function() {
  return {
    barcode:  $(this).attr('barcode'),
    amount:   $(this).attr('amount'),
    previous: $(this).attr('previous')
  }
})
```

In this case you *want* the `this` to be taken from inside of the `function` call,
as it refers to the object, you matched with the `$('input:checked')` call.
If you store `var self = this` as twilson suggested, you would not receive the actual values of the input box, but no values, as the `this` of the calling context is most likely not an `HTMLElement` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You would be best served with an array of objects, rather than just an array.

```
var self = this; // Important because 'this' may change in scope.
var barcodes = []

$("input:checked").each(function(index, item) {
    barcodes.push({
        barcode: $(self).attr("barcode"),
        amount: $(self).attr("value"),
        previous: $(self).attr("previous")
    });
});
```

You will then end up with an array something like this:

```
[
    { barcode: "5049383", amount: "4", previous: "17263742" },
    { barcode: "5049389", amount: "1", previous: "1726376" }
]
```

1. Put the `var` keyword before your variables inside the function otherwise they will are global.
2. `var self = this;` is generally good practice when calling additional functions because the scope of `this` can change quite a bit depending upon your point of execution, usually to become the main jQuery object. `self` give you that pointer back to what you expect to be talking to.

Comment: i make the suggested changes but i receive in alert [object Object],[object Object]    function barcodeTotal() {
    var self = this;
    var barcodes = [];
    $("input:checked").each(function(i, item) {
     barcodes.push({
      barcode : $(self).attr("barcode"), 
      amount : $(self).attr("value"), 
      previous : $(self).attr("previous")
     });
     //barcode[i] = $(this).attr("barcode");
     //barcodeamount[i] = $(this).attr("value");
     //barcodeprevious[i] = $(this).attr("previous");
          });
alert(barcodes);
   }

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
var arrBarCodeDet = new Array();
var objCheckedElem = $("input:checked");
$.map(objCheckedElem,function(elem,index){
    /**
        Result As Object
        arrBarCodeDet[index] = [{'barcode':$(elem).attr("barcode")},{'barcodevalue':$(elem).attr("barcodevalue")}];
    */
    //Result As Arrray
    arrBarCodeDet[index] = new Array();
    arrBarCodeDet[index]['barcode'] = $(elem).attr("barcode");
    arrBarCodeDet[index]['barcodevalue'] = $(elem).attr("barcodevalue");

})
```

});

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1" checked="checked"  barcode="12233"  barcodevalue="12"  />Check Box 1 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="1" checked="checked"  barcode="45451"  barcodevalue="24"  />Check Box 2 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check3" value="1" checked="checked"  barcode="34343"  barcodevalue="36"  />Check Box 3 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check4" value="1"  barcode="32333"  value="48"  />Check Box  <br />
```

Result Will be
arrBarCodeDet
[
Array[0]
barcode: "12233"
barcodevalue: "12"
length: 0
**proto**: Array[0]
, 
Array[0]
barcode: "45451"
barcodevalue: "24"
length: 0
**proto**: Array[0]
, 
Array[0]
barcode: "34343"
barcodevalue: "36"
length: 0
**proto**: Array[0]
]